# Pairs of points on a graph

Tags: math, geometry, unique

There are n points on a graph.
m pairs of these points are joined. No two intersect each other. 
Now (m+1)th pair has to drawn such that it doesn't intersect with any other line segment.
Given number of points and pairs connected, is making  (m+1)th line segment is impossible.

eg: 3 points and 2 pairs : 1-2 and 2-3. Now connecting a 3rd pair is not imposible. so this is accepted.

How to tell if in the given situation, connecting another pair is impossible or not?

Comment: Are you allowed to redraw the graph after adding the edge, or are the positions of the nodes and the specific curves connecting them fixed?

Comment: You may redraw. However it should be impossible to add a new edge any any configuration after joining m pairs.

Comment: Perhaps read about [planar graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) and [Wagner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem).

Comment: Do you mean: "Given n points on a 2-dimensional plane, and m line segments connecting them, is it possible to add another line segment connecting two of the points such that no line segments intersect?" I think that if you reformulate your question you will get a quick answer.

Comment: Yeah thanks.. I will use better language

Comment: I think this help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection

Comment: Are we excluding adding the pair 1-3 in the example since 1 is already in a pair? (as is 3). Or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 0):

Do the line segments have to be straight or can they curve? You can get an answer by looking at the Euler characteristic for convex polyhedra. If you graph contains a face with more than  edges then you can draw an extra line. Try to draw graphs that only contain triangular faces, and guess a relation between V, E, and F. Subsequently try to prove it by induction

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic